in deply , how to select variable which contains string [cat] or [b]?
In dplyr, how to select columns contains cat or b ? select(matches("('cat')('b')")) seems can't work
 library(tidyverse)
    ori_df <- data.frame(ccat_a=1,wt=2,cat_b=1,cf=6,fbw=4)
    ori_df %>% select(matches("('cat')('b')"))


Use contains from tidyselect
ori_df <- data.frame(ccat_a=1,wt=2,cat_b=1,cf=6,fbw=4)
ori_df %>% 
    select(contains(c("cat", "b")))

